# Wait for a notification in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, language-agnostic, notifications, wait

Not strictly related to C++, I am looking for more of a design patter or suggestion on how to approach this.

Say I have

```
class A
{
public:
   void process();
   void wait();
}
```

I will first call `process()`, which (duuh) does some processing and will then call `wait()`. The `wait()` function is supposed to wait for a notification and then exit. I already have the logic for the notification on a separate thread, but I'm not really sure what the best approach for this is.

What I thought of is:

```
void A::wait()
{
   while ( _notificationOccured == false )
   {
   }
}
```

where `_notificationOccured` can be a bool member of `A` that will be changed by the notification. But, again, I'm not sure that this is the best approach. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pooling for a variable gives terrible performance, because pooling thread takes almost all CPU time. You need to use events or messages - this stuff is platform-specific. You can use some portable library for this, for example, Boost.

Comment: I know pooling is bad, that's why I need suggestions. I already have events, but I'm not sure how that would help. Can you expand a little, maybe post some code?

Comment: @Alex: Polling does not have to be bad. Spin-locks do just that.

Comment: If you don't want to use Boost, look at Windows API: CreateEvent, SetEvent, WaitForSingleObject. SetEvent works like your _notificationOccured = true. WaitForSingleObject replaces your busy waiting.

Answer (score 2):

What you do is called [busy waiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting).

The are various techniques to do this better, the simplest would be to use a plain mutex with ncondition notification (win32/pthreads/boost).

Comment: In the link provided, I also see a loop that exits when the variable changes, which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: the Condition Variables section at http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html#SYNCHRONIZATION

Comment: I'm running this on Windows and can't really get boost (not my choice).

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach introduces a power-loop, which will kill the performance of the system you are running on. You should introduce a short sleep-time (10ms will suffice) to prevent that from happening. Better yet, use a library, like [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html) (as @Nim suggested).

Btw, polling like you do is not all bad. In fact, that is what so-called [spin-locks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock) do. The idea is that a short time of polling is more efficient than locking if the expected wait-time is short.

Comment: See the comment on Alex's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Semaphores
2. Conditions

Both are OS specific, boost has support for latter. There are other ways (such as atomic operations, but how these are exposed is compiler specific). IMHO, I would use one of the above.

Comment: @Maxim, there was no mention of OS or any specific mechanism as to how the threads interact. At that point, all that could be provided was a generic mechanism...

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, here is a simple enough example from msdn - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686903(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Nim, if not OS-specific just use `std::async()`.

Comment: @Maxim, that assumes c++11, which again isn't really associated with the question...

Answer (score 0):

I only know this from Windows, so I don't know if this translates easily to other plattforms.

In pseudo code:

```
Timer myTimer(1, MYEVENT); // elapses every second
SetTimer( myTimer );       // register timer with event loop

while( running )
{
  if( GetEvent() == MYEVENT )
  {  

  }
}
```

In Windows GetEvent() is called WaitForSingleObject(...)